# How I can I unit test that a function inside another function was called?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

How I can I unit test that a function inside another function was called? I can't change the source code, so I need to test this as-is.

How can I do this? Here's my code:

```
function B(){ console.log('function b'); }

function A(){
    B();
}
```

Jasmine test:

```
it('should check function B in function A was called', function () {
    spyOn(window, 'B');
    A();
    expect(B).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: I want to add an answer but i think it's mostly opinion. For me, this is a code smell. Unit tests test individual units (modules, functions, classes) in isolation from the rest of the program. Essentially, they test that given an input you get an output. I would recommend moving the nested call and use composition and a tested composition tool instead. something like a `pipe`. `pipe(a,b)(inputToA)` would give you 3 fully tested functions with no mocks or spies. This is a not an opinion held by many so take it with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 0):

> Spies
>
> Jasmine has test double functions called spies. A spy can stub any
>   function and tracks calls to it and all arguments. A spy only exists
>   in the describe or it block in which it is defined, and will be
>   removed after each spec. There are special matchers for interacting
>   with spies. This syntax has changed for Jasmine 2.0. The
>   toHaveBeenCalled matcher will return true if the spy was called. The
>   toHaveBeenCalledWith matcher will return true if the argument list
>   matches any of the recorded calls to the spy.

```
 describe("A spy", function() {
  var foo, bar = null;

  beforeEach(function() {
    foo = {
      setBar: function(value) {
        bar = value;
      }
    };

    spyOn(foo, 'setBar');

    foo.setBar(123);
    foo.setBar(456, 'another param');
  });

  it("tracks that the spy was called", function() {
    expect(foo.setBar).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  it("tracks all the arguments of its calls", function() {
    expect(foo.setBar).toHaveBeenCalledWith(123);
    expect(foo.setBar).toHaveBeenCalledWith(456, 'another param');
  });

  it("stops all execution on a function", function() {
    expect(bar).toBeNull();
  });
});
```